# Union function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, union

I am trying to filter my data, and add the desired data to the Range. I have set my desired range to null and initiated a search in a particular column for a particular keyword, which if found adds the entire row in my Range. 
Column 'E' is been searched for a Value "Desired Value", if found the entire row is added to the PTRange, which is initially set to Nothing(is Empty).

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim PTRange As Range
Dim count As Long
count = 1
Set PTRange = Nothing
Set rng = Range("E2:E20")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = ("Desired Value") Then
        PTRange = Application.Union(Range(PTRange), Range(Rows(count)))
    End If
    count = count + 1
Next cell
```

But the compiler shows that there is something wrong in the code where Union method is used.

UPDATE :
Initialization of PTRange and the following change

```
PTRange=Union(PTRange,Rows(count))
```

worked for me. Thanks

Comment: what error does it Show ? try replacing Union(Range(PTRange) with Union(PTRange, ...

Comment: Range(PTRange) should this just be PTRange, union(rng1,rng2.... where rng1 & 2 are ranges.  Also PTrange wont exist on the 1st pass, so you have to set PTRange=..... the 1st time.

Comment: There is missing `Set ` after `Then`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get you to your desired goal as I'm a little unclear what that is but the below can serve as both assistance on your code with a possible solution following.

Firstly I would recommend you always have `Option Explicit` turned on especially if calling out to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for assistance.

`Option Explicit` forces you to declare all variables, in this instance it would be of help as you `cell` as a variable which can appear ambiguous. When it is not declared, it starts its life as a variant and is defined to a specific format on first use, in this case the compiler declared `cell` as a `Range`.

It also helps encourage better coding and to understand what is happening in the code more. To turn it on, type `Option Explicit` at the very top of the code pane (before any procedures or variable declarations), also while in the VBE (Visual Basic Editor) click 'Tools' > 'Options' and ensure 'Require Variable Declaration' is ticked.

Below are some comments within the code you have, these should help you understand the issues you are facing.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim PTRange As Range
Dim count As Long
count = 1

'If the range is nothing then it can not be used, it must be started as
'something
Set PTRange = Nothing

Set rng = Range("E2:E20")

'This is where declaring 'cell' would help understanding, it will become a 
'Range at the VBE discretion\decision based on what you are trying to do
'with it. Even when looking at a single cell, you do so through a Range,
'it is a reference to one or more cells in a worksheet
For Each cell In rng ' 
    If cell.Value = ("Desired Value") Then
        'This will not work for a number of reasons
        'O- As BrakNicku stated, there needs to be 'Set' at the front
        'O- This is not remembering the values into the 'PTRange' but
        '   adding a reference to where those values are. I.e. You are 
        '   not taking note of everybody in the house, but just remembering
        '   their house address
        'O- You do not need to put 'Range()' around 'PTRange' as it is 
        '   already a range
        'O- 'Rows(count)' is not valid syntax and does not pass a range into 
        '   the union
        'O- 'Union' will put together 2 or more references to ranges, it 
        '   will not put their values in any specific place on a worksheet 
        PTRange = Application.Union(Range(PTRange), Range(Rows(count)))
End If
count = count + 1
Next cell
```

I hope the above has been informative and below is an example to a potential solution:-
    Option Explicit

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim LngRow      As Long
Dim Rng         As Excel.Range
Dim Rng_Cl      As Excel.Range
Dim Rng_PT      As Excel.Range

LngRow = 21

'Initialise my Range
Set Rng_PT = Range("E21") '" & LngRow)

    'Get the search range
    Set Rng = Range("E2:E20")

        'Loop through all the cells
        For Each Rng_Cl In Rng
            If Rng_Cl.Value = ("Duck") Then
                'Adds just 5 column and not the whole row
                Range(Rng_Cl.Address, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rng_Cl.Row, Rng_Cl.Column + 5).Address).Copy Range("E" & LngRow)
                LngRow = LngRow + 1
            End If
        Next

    'It is good practice to remove references once you are done with them
    'This can help with memory consumption/speed and also more serious
    'memory leaks (and actual stack overflows!) on larger macros
    Set Rng = Nothing

Set Rng_PT = Nothing

End Sub
```